# What's the idea behind constructing the radical axis?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, power-of-the-point

I know how to construct it, but I don't understand why every point in the radical axis has the same power of a point with respect of the two circumferences.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is by a definition. Radical axis is a set of points that have equal power to both circles.

Now you have to prove that radical axis is actually a line.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $K$ has the same power with both circles:
$$
KB^2-r^2=KV^2-R^2.
$$
Then any other point $J$ on the perpendicular at $K$ also has the same power, because by Pythagoras theorem we have:
$$
JB^2-r^2=JK^2+KB^2-r^2=JK^2+KV^2-R^2=JV^2-R^2.
$$

Comment: Well this is not complete. How do you know there is no other points out of this perpendicular?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Radical_axis

Comment: What about it?...